# How to compare two adjacent items in the same list - Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am searching for a way to compare two adjacent items in a list, eg. comparing which has a higher value, and then I will sort them accordingly. It is a list the user will be inputting, so it is not a case of just 
`if l[1] > l[2]`, as I will not know the length of the list, so
I will need a general statement for use in a for loop.

I had the idea of having something akin to 
    `for i in l:
    if x > i[index of x + 1]`
 but do not know how to find the index of the variable.
Any help appreciated, Thank you

EDIT: I am aware of the built in sort function, but just wanted to practice coding and algorithm-writing by creating my own :)

Comment: Do you want to sort your list?

Answer (score 29):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [23]: lis = [1,7,8,4,5,3]

In [24]: for x, y in zip(lis, lis[1:]):
   ....:     print x, y           # prints the adjacent elements
             # do something here
   ....:     
1 7
7 8
8 4
4 5
5 3
```

Comment: @Lattyware actually it's you who beat me by 3 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

The quick-and-ugly solution would be this (don't use it!):

```
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    # here you can use lst[i + 1] as long as i + 1 < len(lst)
```

However, **do not** implement list sorting by yourself! Use `.sort()` to sort in-place or `sorted()` if you want to create a new list instead. There is a [really good guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) on how to sort things on the python website.

If that's not your intention.. instead of the loop I posted above there's also a much nicer way to iterate over chunks from a list in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991553/298479):

```
import itertools
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

You use to like this:

```
for x, y in grouper(2, lst):
    # do whatever. in case of an odd element count y is None in the last iteration
```

Comment: I did want to sort the list, and am aware of the sort function, it's just an exercise I have set myself to practice coding, rather than a functional thing

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining how that second method you suggested works? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use inbuilt reduce function

e.g. :

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def my_function(a,b):
    # your comparison between a and b
    # return or print values or what ever you want to do based on the comparison


reduce(my_function, l)
```

reduce will automatically take care of i and i + 1.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: how does my function pass the argument from reduce ? Are a, b elements of list ?

Answer (score 0):

there is built in function [cmp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp), which you can use for the comparison

I needed to check if all items in list are identical, so I did this:

```
def compare(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return x
    return False

reduce(compare, my_list)
```

When you run this with say [1,1,1,1,1,1], it prints 1, when one of numbers doesn't match, it returns False .. simple

Comment: `cmp` is Python 2 only.  For Python 3, there are a lot of useful functions like this in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) built-in