# Compare two adjacent elements in same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have already gone through a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012562/how-to-compare-two-adjacent-items-in-the-same-list-python) but I want to know what I did wrong in my code while using `for` loop.

List `a` given as:

```
a = [2, 4, 7,1,9, 33]
```

All I want to compare two adjacent elements as :

```
2 4
4 7
7 1
1 9
9 33
```

I did something like:

```
for x in a:
    for y in a[1:]:
        print (x,y)
```

Answer (score 11):

Your outer loop persists for *each* value in your inner loop. To compare adjacent elements, you can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) a list with a *shifted version* of itself. The shifting can be achieved through [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation):

```
for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]):
    print(x, y)
```

In the *general* case, where your input is any iterable rather than a list (or another iterable which supports indexing), you can use the [`itertools` `pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available in the [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise) library:

```
from more_itertools import pairwise

for x, y in pairwise(a):
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a stable element with all of the elements in the list but the first.

The correct way would be:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    x = a[i]
    y = a[i+1]
    print (x,y)
```