# How to compare neighboring elements in a single list in python without using library?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to get a python function which judges whether a number is written in ascending or descending order (eg 12345 --> ascending, 54321 --> descending, 12321 --> neither).

For this, I first tried making a number into a string type and then converted to a list:

```py
n=12321
for i in list(str(n)):
```

But then how can I finish comparing each digits of number to show that n belongs to neither?

Are there some ways I could do this without using specific libraries?

Comment: Just so you know, you can iterate over a string directly: `for i in str(n)`

Comment: As far as your question goes, try looking at two elements at a time either using indexing over the length of the `n` string (how many digits), or using `zip` with slicing: `n_string = str(n); for a, b in zip(n_string, n_string[1:])`. You'll still need to add your comparison logic. There are other ways too. Like building a `range` object from the largest and smallest digit and comparing your digits, which you'd need to cast to `int`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611711/compare-two-adjacent-elements-in-same-list