# Iterate over two lists

Tags: python, loops, iteration, selection-sort

I want to iterate over 2 lists, and compare elements from the same list to see if higher or lower.
something like

high = [5,7,8,4,2 ... 3]
low = [16,4,8,1,48 ... 4]

if number in high > than previous number, add it to the high_list
if number in low < previous number, add it to the low_list

output would be

high_list = [5,7,8]
low_list = [16,4,1]

```
def iter_num (high,low):
    some_listH = []
    some_listL = []
    for H,L in zip(high,low):
        x = H +1
        if H > H[x]:
            H = H[x]
            some_listH.append(H)
        if L < L[x]:
            L = L[x]
            some_listL.append(L)
        return some_listH, some_listL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I am not sure what your question is.  What do you want to do (that you did mention), what have you tried, what problem are you running into?

Comment: I can get this to work in C# but not familiar with python and trying to get correct indentation is annoying

Comment: I can fix the indentation but not sure what the code is supposed to do.  Perhaps if you also showed the C# code that would help.

Comment: @Basya 
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
It doesnt like me indexing using x.

Comment: If your work is with two lists separately, comparing elements in a list to elements in the same list, not the other list, it would seem to make more sense to iterate over the lists separately.

Comment: Thanks for giving the description of the error; it would be even better to edit that into the question.

Comment: What are you passing in for the parameters?  Are they the lists?  You mentioned two lists...   Are they lists of floating point numbers?

Comment: Are you basically trying to compare list[i] with list[i+1]?

Comment: @Basya I think ill re-post my question, but thanks for the help

Comment: you can look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012562/how-to-compare-two-adjacent-items-in-the-same-list-python

Comment: @Basya yeah exactly just like insertion sort algorithm

Comment: You don't need to post a separate question; you can edit the existing one.

Comment: I think the answer in that link could help you.

Comment: The question is much clearer now.  Have you looked at the link I put in a previous comment?

Comment: @Basya yes, the linked helped, thank you. I just need to workout how to make the example wok for for two lists. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have written:

```
 H > H[x]
```

Either H is an element of a list, or it is a list.  It is not both.

The two lists essentially have nothing to do with eachother.  If they are not guaranteed to be the same length, I would not recommend handling them in the same loop.

This should do what you want for one list.  You can figure out from this how you want to handle the second list, put it into a function, etc.

```
list = [5,7,8,4,2,1,1,1,3]
some_listL = []

some_listL.append(list[0])
for x, y in zip(list, list[1:]):
    if y > x:
        some_listL.append(y)

print (some_listL)
```

To give credit where credit is due, I learned how to do this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012562/how-to-compare-two-adjacent-items-in-the-same-list-python)

Comment: The desired result would be [5,7,8] this returns [5,7,8,3]

Comment: you'll have to tune the comparison.  According to the way I understood your description, if a number was bigger than the previous one, it should be added to the new list.  3 is bigger than 1.  Adjust the comparison however you need; the building blocks are here.

Comment: Thanks man, I slept on it, realised I didnt need to iterate x,y in the same list. Rather x = 0 and if x < item in list, x = item in list
Really appreciate your help

Comment: A pleasure.  BTW, the way it works on this site, you say 'thank you' by upvoting the question.  For the original poster (in this case, you), there is also the option of accepting the answer, if it solved your problem, by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.