# Print only a certain number of characters in Python

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python)

Say I have a string of 492 characters stored in a single variable.  How might I print out the first 50 characters, then go to the next line, then print out the next 50, finally printing a line with 42 characters?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't think this is a duplicate. But I, like you, probably _would_ solve this problem by using that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
chars_per_line = 50
for i in range(0, len(s), chars_per_line):
    print s[i:i+chars_per_line]
```

Comment: A small thing, but shouldn't you be adding `i+chars_per_line` and not `i+50`?

Comment: Yes, good point. Edited.

Comment: Won't you get an IndexError on the last line, since it only has 42 characters?

Comment: @fizzisist Why not try it yourself? (No.)

Comment: @frb You're right! Ignore me...

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in mystring.splitlines():
    print line[:50]
```

Comment: It looks like the OP has one long string that may not necessary contain newlines.

Comment: @JoelCornett My impression from "then go to the next line" was that it was a multi-line string. @Duncan?

Comment: @AlexL: The fact that, given 492 characters of input, it prints a bunch of 50-character lines and then a 42-character line implies that Joel Cornett's guess is right. Otherwise, that 42 would be a huge coincidence. (Still, it would be nice for the OP to confirm.)

Comment: @abarnert Agreed. You're probably right, but I think it's better to have answers for both interpretations of the question until we know either way

Comment: @JoelCornett is right. The input is a single string without newlines; it's the output that should have multiple lines.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [363]: mystr = "A"*492

In [364]: print '\n'.join(mystr[i*width:(i+1)*width] for i in range(int(math.ceil(float(len(mystr))/width))))
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: This needs an `import this` :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Martijn Pieters implied, this would be trivially easy if you had a way to [iterate an iterator by chunks (of n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python). And if you read that question, you *do* have a way to do that.

So, given the `grouper` implementation from the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) (or anything else you prefer from that other question):

```
lines = [''.join(group) for group in grouper(50, my_string, '')]
```

Or, if you just want to print them out:

```
for group in grouper(50, my_string, ''):
    print ''.join(group)
```

Once you know that `grouper` exists, I think this is simpler than Joel Cornett's answer. Note that his didn't work in the first version, and had to be fixed; this one is pretty much impossible to get wrong. Anything that eliminates the possibility of fencepost errors is usually better; that's why we have `for`-`in` loops and `enumerate` instead of C-style `for` loops, and so on.

Here it is in action:

```
>>> my_string='1234567890'*49+'12'
>>> print my_string
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
>>> # That was ugly…
>>> for group in grouper(50, my_string, ''):
...     print ''.join(group)
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
>>> # Pretty!
```

Comment: I see it now.  It's just that my limited newbie lexicon doesn't include anything like "iterated iterators" ;-)

Comment: @DuncanWadsworth: Yeah, the terminology is a bit hard to figure out if you don't already know what you're looking to figure out. But the concept is simple, once you get it: You have a string with 492 characters, and you want to group them 50 at a time. A string is just a kind of iterable, so a general way to group iterables would give you a way to group strings. All simple—except if you didn't already know about the general iterable concept, you couldn't even think to ask for such a general solution, much less find it on your own.