# How to print several array elements per line to text file

Tags: python, list, output, text-files

I have a 1D array e.g. `arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ...]` of arbitrary length.

How do I print this to a text file (with integers/floats separated by spaces) so that every 7 elements are printed on the same line in the text file?

So I want the text file to look like this:

Line 1:`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Line 2:`8 9 10 11 12 13 14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this:

```
liNums = xrange(1, 20)
x = 0
line = ""
for i in liNums:
    x+=1
    line += "%s " % i
    if not x%7:
        line += "\n"
#send line to output, here I will just print it
print line
```

here every 7 items a new line is appended... output looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19
```

hope that helps!

Comment: You have a good algorithm (I have the same !). Use a generator and ``enumerate()`` and you'll have got the Python spirit

Comment: I see what you mean, yield the line instead of just appending \n when I answered this question I wrote down the first thing that would have popped into my head with that problem :p

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be broken down into 3 parts:

1. How to divide a list of arbitrary size into chunks of a specific length
2. How to print a list of ints/floats using a space as delimiter
3. How to write to a file

### Dividing a list of arbitrary size into chunks of a specific length

Using the `grouper` method as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python/8991553#8991553):

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
       chunk = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
       if not chunk:
           return
       yield chunk
```

you can easily split a list of arbitrary length to chunks of a desired length. For example:

```
>>> arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> for chunk in grouper(7, arr1): print chunk
... 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
(15, 16)
```

### Printing a list of ints/floats using a space as delimiter

The standard way to join a list into a string is to use [`string.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join). However, that only works for lists of strings so we'll need to first convert each element into its string representation. Here's one way:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print " ".join(str(x) for x in a)
1 2 3 4
```

Using this method in the previous example, we get:

```
>>> for chunk in grouper(7, arr1):
...   print " ".join(str(x) for x in chunk)
... 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16
```

That's pretty much the output you want. Now all we need to do is write that to a file.

### Writing to a file

```
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
  for chunk in grouper(7, arr1):
    f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in chunk) + "\n")
```

For details, see [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> for i in xrange(0,len(arr1),7):
...     print arr1[i:i+7]
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

or you could do:

```
>>> arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> results = map(str,arr1)
>>> for i in range(0,len(arr1),7):
...     ','.join(results[i:i+7])
... 
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7'
'8,9,10,11,12,13,14'
```

Comment: Reliably simple, that's better than heavy machinery. You can improve speed of writing by doing ``'\n'.join(','.join(results[i:i+7]) for i in range(0,len(arr1),7))``.

Answer (score 2):

```
output=''
col = 0
for i in arr1:
    output +="%s " % i #write an element of the array to the output and append a space
    col += 1 #count the number of elements on the current line
    if col==7: #if 7 elements have been entered, append a new line and restart the count
        output += "\n"
        col = 0

f = open("filepath.txt",'w') #open a file (replace filepath.txt with the actual filename)
f.write(output) # write the output to the text file
f.close() #close the file object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [arr1[7 * i: 7 * i + 7] for i in range(0, 1 + len(arr1) / 7)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15]]
```

Then you just have to iterate in this list (of lists), to insert them in the file.

Comment: Probably would be better to make that a generator expression instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: I think this doesn't do what you want if `len(arr1)%7 == 0`. Try `(6+len(arr1))/7`.

Comment: Yes it does: it gives `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` if `arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Or did I misunderstand you ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import imap
print '\n'.join((' '.join(imap(str, arr1[i*7:(i+1)*7])) for i in xrange((6+len(arr1))/7)))
```

Or,

```
 groups_of_seven = (arr1[i*7:(i+1)*7] for i in xrange((6+len(arr1))/7))
 groups_of_seven_strings = (imap(str, i) for i in groups_of_seven)
 groups_of_strings = (' '.join(i) for i in groups_of_seven_strings)
 one_string = '\n'.join(groups_of_strings)
```

Combining the nested `join`s with the `izip` technique:

```
print '\n'.join((' '.join(j) for j in izip(*[imap(str, arr1)]*7)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chunk a sequence using this `zip` idiom:

```
from itertools import izip

def chunk(seq, n):
    return izip(*[iter(seq)]*n)
```

You can then compose an iterator for `writelines`:

```
def chunkedlines(seq, n):
    for line in chunk(seq, 7):
        yield ' '.join(str(item) for item in line)
        yield "\n"
```

Finally use it:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
fp = StringIO('wb')

arr1 = range(1, 15)

fp.writelines(chunkedlines(arr1, 7))

print fp.getvalue()
```

Comment: ``izip(*[iter(seq)]*n)``  Phew !! I don't know if it's very fast, but it's tricky ! It works because ``[iter(seq)]*n`` creates a list of length ``n`` with all elements being equal to the same iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, think "generator" !

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,101,
      203,514,201,567,849]

gen = ('%-5s\n' % x if i%7==0 else '%-5s' %x
       for i,x in enumerate(li,1))

print ''.join(gen)
```

result

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    
8    9    10   11   12   13   14   
101  203  514  201  567  849
```

And if you want to parameterize the number of numbers in each line, create a generator function:

```
def yn(li,n):
    for i,x in enumerate(li,1):
        yield '%-5s ' % x
        if i%n==0:
            yield '\n'

print ''.join(yn(li,7))
```