# How to write a list to a file with two items per row

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to save the following list to a CSV file:

```
import csv

list = ['52.26.17.68', 'TotalPhysicalMemory : 4294361088', '10.12.15.14', 'TotalPhysicalMemory : 6546534654']

with open('testing.csv', 'w', newline='') as r:
        writer = csv.writer(r, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(list)
```

With this my CSV file looks like:

[image]

How can I get "TotalPhysicalMemory" into column B so it looks like below?

[image]

Comment: Also: [How to print several array elements per line to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14941854/7851470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` with list slicing

**Ex:**

```
import csv

lst = ['52.26.17.68', 'TotalPhysicalMemory : 4294361088', '10.12.15.14', 'TotalPhysicalMemory : 6546534654']

with open('testing.csv', 'w', newline='') as r:
    writer = csv.writer(r, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
```

Comment: This puts the data in one column for me.

Comment: You probably need to use delimiter as tab while opening the file in excel

Comment: changing delimiter to "," worked. Thanks for your help.