# Grabbing values of an array in sets of 100

Tags: python, arrays, steam-web-api

In the code below, `ids` is an array which contains the steam64 ids of all users in your friendslist.  Now according to the steam web api documentation, `GetPlayerSummaries` only takes a list of 100 comma separated steam64 ids. Some users have more than 100 friends, and instead of running a for loop 200 times that each time calls the API, I want to take array in sets of 100 steam ids. What would be the most efficient way to do this (in terms of speed)?

I know that I can do `ids[0:100]` to grab the first 100 elements of an array, but how I accomplish doing this for a friendlist of say 230 users?

```
def getDescriptions(ids):
    sids = ','.join(map(str, ids)) 
    r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='+API_KEY+'&steamids=' + sids)
    data = r.json();
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130042/189134) answer, you are able to break this into groups of 100 (or less for the last loop) of friends.

```
def chunkit(lst, n):
    newn = int(len(lst)/n)
    for i in xrange(0, n-1):
        yield lst[i*newn:i*newn+newn]
    yield lst[n*newn-newn:]


def getDescriptions(ids):
    friends = chunkit(ids, 3)
    while (True):
        try:
            fids = friends.next()
            sids = ','.join(map(str, fids)) 
            r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='+API_KEY+'&steamids=' + sids)
            data = r.json()
            # Do something with the data variable
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

This will create iterators broken into 3 (second parameter to `chunkit`) groups. I chose 3, because the base size of the friends list is 250. You can get more (rules from [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124146/42371) post), but it is a safe place to start. You can fine tune that value as you need.

Utilizing this method, your `data` value will be overwritten each loop. Make sure you do something with it at the place indicated.

Comment: would it be easier to use this code

`def chunksiter(l, chunks):
    i,j,n = 0,0,0
    rl = []
    while n < len(l)/chunks:        
        rl.append(l[i:j+chunks])        
        i+=chunks
        j+=j+chunks        
        n+=1
    return iter(rl)`

and use this code with `chunks = 100`

Answer (score -1):

I have an easy alternative, just reduce your list size on each `while/loop` until exhaustion:

```
def getDescriptions(ids):
    sids = ','.join(map(str, ids))
    sids_queue = sids.split(',')
    data = []
    while len(sids_queue) != 0:
        r = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='+ \
                            API_KEY+'&steamids=' + ','.join(sids_queue[:100])
        data.append(r.json) # r.json without (), by the way
        # then skip [0:100] and reassign to sids_queue, you get the idea
        sids_queue = sids_queue[101:]
```

Comment: @Andy, The document you show probably is wrong, as I try their example and it gives me a nice `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: The document is not incorrect. Your code results in this (for one iteration through your loop): `[<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>]`. Additionally, your `.get` throws this error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Comment: @Andy thanks for spotting it. I edited and put `join` to the list now