# Python consume an iterator pair-wise

Tags: python, iterator, pysam

I am trying to understand Python's iterators in the context of the [pysam module](http://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). By using the `fetch` method on a so called AlignmentFile class one get a proper iterator `iter` consisting of records from the file `file`. I can the use various methods to access each record (iterable), for instance the name with `query_name`:

```
import pysam
iter = pysam.AlignmentFile(file, "rb", check_sq=False).fetch(until_eof=True)
for record in iter:
  print(record.query_name)
```

It happens that records come in pairs so that one would like something like:

```
while True:
  r1 = iter.__next__() 
  r2 = iter.__next__()
  print(r1.query_name)     
  print(r2.query_name)
```

Calling **next**() is probably not the right way for million of records, but how can one use a for loop to consume the same iterator in pairs of iterables. I looked at the grouper recipe from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and the SOs [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python) (even a duplicate!) and [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) but cannot get it to work.

Comment: *"cannot get it to work"* - what precisely did you try, and what went wrong? Give a [mcve]. Note you should generally call `next(thing)`, not `thing.__next__()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't use the variable name `iter`, because that's already the name of a builtin function.

To answer your question, simply use `itertools.izip` (Python 2) or `zip` (Python 3) on the iterator.

Your code may look as simple as

```
for next_1, next_2 in zip(iterator, iterator):
    # stuff
```

edit: whoops, my original answer was the correct one all along, don't mind the itertools recipe.

edit 2: Consider `itertools.izip_longest` if you deal with iterators that could yield an uneven amount of objects:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> iterator = (x for x in (1,2,3))
>>> 
>>> for next_1, next_2 in izip_longest(iterator, iterator):
...     next_1, next_2
... 
(1, 2)
(3, None)
```

Comment: Yes so I have one iterator only that I want to go through adding every second iterable into r1 and r2.

Comment: @user3375672 there's nothing preventing you from providing the same argument twice to `zip`, i.e. `iterator_1 == iterator_2`.