# Many dictionaries using massive amounts of RAM

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, memory, optimization

I have a very simple Python script to create (for test purposes), 35 million dictionary objects within a list. Each dictionary object contains two key/value pairs. eg.

```
{'Name': 'Jordan', 'Age': 35}
```

The script very simply take a query on name and age, searches through the list of dictionaries and returns a new list containing the index of all matching dictionary entries.

However as you can see below, *an insane amount of memory is consumed*. I presume I am making a very naive mistake somewhere.

[image: screenshot of code and task manager show ram usage]

My code is as follows: (can also be viewed in the image if more readable).

```
import sys

# Firstly, we will create 35 million records in memory, all will be the same apart from one

def search(key, value, data, age):
    print("Searching, please wait")
    # Create list to store returned PKs
    foundPKS = []
    for index in range(0, len(data)):
        if key in data[index] and 'Age' in data[index]:
            if data[index][key] == value and data[index]['Age'] >= age:
                foundPKS.append(index)
    results = foundPKS
    return results

def createdata():
    # Let's create our list for storing our dictionaries
    print("Creating database, please wait")
    dictList = []
    for index in range(0, 35000000):
        # Define dictionary
        record = {'Name': 'Jordan', 'Age': 25}
        if 24500123 <= index <= 24500200:
            record['Name'] = 'Chris'
            record['Age'] = 33
        # Add the dict to a list
        dictList.append(record)
    return dictList

datareturned = createdata()

keyname = input("For which key do you wish to search?")
valuename = input("Which values do you want to find?")
valueage = input("What is the minimum age?")

print("Full data set object size:" + str(sys.getsizeof(datareturned)))
results = search(keyname, valuename, datareturned, int(valueage))

if len(results) > 0:
    print(str(len(results)) + " found. Writing to results.txt")
    fo = open("results.txt", "w")
    for line in range(0, len(results)):
        fo.write(str(results[line]) + "\n")
    fo.close()
```

What is causing the massive consumption of RAM?

Comment: Yeah, don't use 36 million dicts. Use a tuple or better yet, a namedtuple

Comment: I presume the RAM usage is caused by the overhead required by a dict, as the raw string data only makes about 250 - 300MB?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The overhead for a `dict` object is quite large. It depends on your Python version and your system architechture, but on Python 3.5 64bit

```
In [21]: sys.getsizeof({})
Out[21]: 288
```

So guesstimating:

```
250*36e6*1e-9 == 9.0
```

So that is a lower limit on my ram usage in **gigabytes** if I created that many dictionaries, not factoring in the `list`!

Rather than use a dict as a record type, which isn't really the use case, use a `namedtuple`.

And to get a view of how this compares, let's set up an equivalent list of tuples:

```
In [23]: Record = namedtuple("Record", "name age")

In [24]: records = [Record("john", 28) for _ in range(36000000)]

In [25]: getsizeof = sys.getsizeof
```

Consider:

```
In [31]: sum(getsizeof(record)+ getsizeof(record.name) + getsizeof(record.age)  for record in records)
Out[31]: 5220000000

In [32]: _ + getsizeof(records)
Out[32]: 5517842208

In [33]: _ * 1e-9
Out[33]: 5.517842208
```

So 5 gigs is an upper limit that is quite conservative. For example, it assumes that there is no small-int caching going on, which for a record-type of *ages* will totally matter. On my own system, the python process is registering 2.7 gigs of memory usage (via `top`).

So, what is actually going on in my machine is better modeled by being conservative for strings assuming -- unique strings that have an average size of 10, so no string interning -- but liberal for ints, assuming int-caching is taking care of our `int` objects for us, so we just have to worry about the 8-byte pointers!

```
In [35]: sum(getsizeof("0123456789") + 8  for record in records)
Out[35]: 2412000000

In [36]: _ + getsizeof(records)
Out[36]: 2709842208

In [37]: _ * 1e-9
Out[37]: 2.709842208
```

Which is a good model for what I'm observing from `top`.

#### If you really want efficient storage

Now, if you really want to cram data into ram, you are going to have to lose the flexibility of Python. You could use the `array` module in combination with `struct`, to get C-like memory efficiency. An easier world to wade into might be `numpy` instead, which allows for similar things. For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: recordtype = np.dtype([('name', 'S20'),('age', np.uint8)])

In [3]: records = np.empty((36000000), dtype=recordtype)

In [4]: records.nbytes
Out[4]: 756000000

In [5]: records.nbytes*1e-9
Out[5]: 0.756
```

Note, we are now allowed to be quite compact. I can use 8-bit unsigned integers (i.e. a single byte) to represent age. However, immediately I am faced with some inflexibility: if I want efficient storage of strings I must define a maximum size. I've used `'S20'`, which is 20 characters. These are ASCII bytes, but a field of 20 ascii characters might very well suffice for names.

Now, `numpy` gives you a lot of fast methods wrapping C-compiled code. So, just to play around with it, let's fill our records with some toy data. Names will simply be string of digits from a simple count, and age will be selected from a normal distribution with a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 10.

```
In [8]: for i in range(1, 36000000+1):
   ...:     records['name'][i - 1] = b"%08d" % i
   ...:

In [9]: import random
   ...: for i in range(36000000):
   ...:     records['age'][i] = max(0, int(random.normalvariate(50, 10)))
   ...:
```

Now, we can use numpy to query our `records`. For example, if you want the indices of your records *given some condition*, use `np.where`:

```
In [10]: np.where(records['age'] > 70)
Out[10]: (array([      58,      146,      192, ..., 35999635, 35999768, 35999927]),)

In [11]: idx = np.where(records['age'] > 70)[0]

In [12]: len(idx)
Out[12]: 643403
```

So `643403` records that have an age `> 70`. Now, let's try `100`:

```
In [13]: idx = np.where(records['age'] > 100)[0]

In [14]: len(idx)
Out[14]: 9

In [15]: idx
Out[15]:
array([ 2315458,  5088296,  5161049,  7079762, 15574072, 17995993,
       25665975, 26724665, 28322943])

In [16]: records[idx]
Out[16]:
array([(b'02315459', 101), (b'05088297', 102), (b'05161050', 101),
       (b'07079763', 104), (b'15574073', 101), (b'17995994', 102),
       (b'25665976', 101), (b'26724666', 102), (b'28322944', 101)],
      dtype=[('name', 'S20'), ('age', 'u1')])
```

Of course, one major inflexibility is that `numpy` arrays are *sized*. Resizing operations are expensive. Now, you could maybe wrap a `numpy.array` in some class and it will act as an efficient backbone, but at that point, you might as well use a real data-base. Lucky for you, Python comes with `sqlite`.

Comment: Looks like a namedtuple is going to be a winner if I do want to maintain the data in-memory. Very useful, thanks.

Comment: @Jordan I'm about to add a comparison

Comment: @Jordan comparison added.

Comment: That's a worthy improvement indeed. Thanks for adding. I'm also going to investigate some compression techniques for further reducing RAM utilisation.

Comment: @Jordan Well, you can use `numpy` if you want to cram as much into memory as possible. Or the `array` module, in combinations with `struct`, which can give you the compactness of C if you really need it, but a lot of the nice flexibility of Python is lost... but at least you are still writing code in Python!

Comment: This is beyond an excellent answer. You didn't just provide options but ran clear, documented tests to demonstrate the solutions considered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this

```
>>> import sys 
>>> sys.getsizeof({'Name': 'Jordan', 'Age': 25}) * 35000000
10080000000
```

So ~10 GB. Python is doing exactly what you are asking it to do.

You need to split this up into chucks and check them sequentially.Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python) as a starting point

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. I do actually want the data to remain in-memory for performance. It seems that a Dict consumes quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: @Jordan - `pandas` might also be a good option. It would also make the search and matching a lot easier since `pandas` has that functionality built it... or just buy moar RAM :)

Answer (score 0):

> ... 35 million dictionary objects within a list. Each dictionary object
>   contains two key/value pairs. eg.  {'Name': 'Jordan', 'Age': 35}

You're right that this manner of storage has considerable overhead.

The [Flyweight Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) suggests that the solution involves factoring-out the commonalities.  Here are two ideas for alternative storage of the same data with better space utilization.

You can use [__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to save space on instances of classes (this suppresses the creation of per-instance dictionaries):

```
class Person(object):
    __slots__ = ['Name', 'Age']

s = [Person('Jordan', 35), Person('Martin', 31), Person('Mary', 33)]
```

It is even more space-efficient to use dense data structures like a pair of parallel lists:

```
s_name = ['Jordan', 'Martin', 'Mary']
s_age = [35, 31, 33]
```

If there duplicates in the data, you save even more space by [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) the values:

```
s_name = map(intern, s_name)
```

Or in Python 3:

```
s_name = list(map(sys.intern, s_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is compact approach to have millions small objects, which require less memory than with `__slots__`.

```
pip3 install recordclass

from recordclass import dataobject

class Person(dataobject):
   name:str
   age:int
```

Each instance save 16 bytes for python>=3.8 and 24 bytes for python<3.8