# Why would memory overhead of dictionary of data be double that of the same data on disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to load a dataset from file containing approximately 3 million json-serialized objects. Each object is a large nested dictionary containing a variety of types -- ints, floats, lists, and other dictionaries.

The size of the file on disk is approximately 60GB. I have over 128GB of ram so I should be able to fit the whole set in memory. However, when I load the data into a large dictionary using the following code, the size of used memory increases to at least 110GB (it might even get larger but I stopped the script before it grew any more.)

What could explain the memory overhead I am seeing when I try to load this data? Why would 60GB on disk translate to 110GB or more in memory? As far as I can tell, the only overhead here should be the result of creating list containers for objects, and for assigning those lists a key name in the results dictionary. That can't possibly account for almost twice as much memory as the data itself -- can it?

```
def load_by_geohash(file, specificity=7):
    results = defaultdict(list)
    filename = os.path.join(DATADIR, file)

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        updates = (json.loads(line) for line in f)
        for update in updates:
            geo_hash = update['geohash'][:specificity]
            results[geo_hash].append(update)

    return results
```

Comment: What sort of things are in `update['geohash'][:specificity]`? `int` objects? `float` objects? `str` objects?

Comment: If your data is a tiny object, then the size of the container matters. For example, I am pretty sure that the data in a Python `int` is significantly larger than the size of the data, especially for small numbers.

Comment: Can you load subsets of your data with increasing sizes and make a graph of memory consumption? Each single new object has a certain minimum memory footprint.

Comment: The `geo_hash` keys are strings. Each update object is a large nested dictionary.

Comment: Without seeing your input, this is impossible to reproduce or answer definitively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it easily could. Consider a simple case of a list of strings:

```
>>> import json
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> x = ['a string', 'another string', 'yet another']
>>> sum(map(getsizeof, x)) + getsizeof(x)
268
>>> len(json.dumps(x).encode())
45
>>>
```

In Python, everything is an object. So every (well, most) individual objects have *at least* `sys.getsizeof(object())` overhead. Note, an empty string on my system:

```
>>> getsizeof('')
49
```

Note, this discrepancy is even greater for `dict` objects, consider:

```
>>> d
{'a': 'a string', 'b': 'another string', 'c': 'yet another'}
>>> sum(map(getsizeof, d)) + sum(map(getsizeof, d.values())) + getsizeof(d)
570
>>> len(json.dumps(d).encode())
60
```

It is downright enormous for the case of an empty dict:

```
>>> getsizeof({}), len(json.dumps({}).encode())
(240, 2)
```

Now, there are various options for storing your data more compactly. But this depends on your use-case.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578843/many-dictionaries-using-massive-amounts-of-ram/) is a related question about the memory usage of many dictionaries. There is also an example of using `numpy` arrays and `namedtuple` objects to store data more compactly. Note, using `namedtuple` objects might be what you need, the memory savings are potentially huge because you don't need to store actual string objects for the keys. If your sub-dictionary structure is regular, I suggest replacing those nested `update` dict's with nested `namedtuple` objects.