# How to break a big list into many small list

Tags: list, python-3.6

```
['1899', 'Horsey', '1909', 'Ford', '1911', 'Overland',]
```

For example, I want to convert the above list into this form:

```
['1899', 'Horsey']['1909', 'Ford']['1911', 'Overland']
```

How can I do that? I'm very new to python.

Comment: An efficient way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in python

```
Origlist = ['1899', 'Horsey', '1909', 'Ford', '1911', 'Overland',]
sublistsize = 2
sublists = [Origlist [x:x+sublistsize] for x in range(0,len(Origlist ),sublistsize)]
```

Comment: im running your code and get [['1899', 'Horsey'], ['1909', 'Ford'], ['1911', 'Overland'], ['1958', 'Ford'], ['1961', 'Amphicar'], ['1961', 'Corvair']], but i wanna remove the outside brackets  to make like: ['1899', 'Horsey']    ['1909', 'Ford']  ['1958', 'Ford']  how can i achieve that?

Comment: So you want these to save in some variable to use later or just print in the form you have mentioned ?