# Python: how to programmatically create a dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have an array `a` that I want to store every 5 values of in a dictionary, while programmatically creating keys.

For example:

if we have

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want the dictionary to look like this:

```
d={"first_title":[1,2,3,4,5], "second_title":[6,7,8,9,10]}
```

Edit: I have thousands of terms so I want to do this in a loop

Comment: How do you envision "programmatically creating keys"?

Comment: `a` is a list, not an array.  Slicing into regular chunks is handled in many other questions and other help sites.  Where are you stuck on that part?

Comment: The `d` in your example is not a dictionary, it uses illegal notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

**Input:**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
keys = [1984, 1985, 1986, 1987] 
n = 5
```

**Code:**

```
my_dict = {}

for i in range(len(a)//n):
    key = str(keys[i]) if i < len(keys) else "after " + str(keys[-1])
    my_dict[key] = a[i*n: (i+1)*n]

print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1984': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '1985': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

---

Depending on your use case you could also do something like this:

```
# Input
a = range(22)
keys = [1984, 1985, 1986] # maybe replace it with range(1984, 2000)
n = 5

# Code
b = a
my_dict = {}

for i in range(min(len(keys), len(a)//n)):
    key = keys[min(i, len(keys)-1)]
    my_dict[key] = b[:n]
    b = b[n:]

my_dict['later'] = b

print(my_dict)

# Output
{
    1984: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    1985: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    1986: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    'later': [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary values can be any object, including arrays. So, you just start with an empty dict, and add array values to it.

```
my_dict = {}
year = 1984
for index in range(0, len(a), 5):
    my_dict[year] = a[index: index+5]
    year += 1
```

Comment: I have thousands of terms, so I wanted to do this in some type of loop

Comment: @BobelLegend: what are the keys of the dictionary??

Comment: I want the keys to be a year. Such as 1984, 1985, etc.

Comment: If you want the keys to be years, why don't you say so in the question?

Comment: @Current revision of your answer: you wrote it under the wrong assumption that the array contains entries [1,2,...n] so you substituted it with `range(n)`. The op stated that he has an [arbitary] array so one could assume that the numbers are only an example...

Comment: @FabianN.:edited

Comment: I like this one, its clean, short, pythonic and works on an arbitrary length of a, would be really nice if we would now the actual use case...

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat general and pythonic solution is the following:

```
from itertools import izip_longest


def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    """grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"""
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

keys = ["first-title", "second-title"]
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = {key: list(group) for key, group in zip(keys, grouper(5, a))}
```

This uses the grouper recipe (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python) for a better explanation). A less pythonic solution, is to iterate over the pair of keys and groups using a for loop:

```
result = {}
for key, group in zip(keys, grouper(5, a)):
    result[key] = group
```

In both cases the output is:

```
{'first-title': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'second-title': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic but: +1 for using dict comprehension, I didn't even know that this is possible.