# python string manipulation to match windows firewall syntax

Tags: python, string

I have a string like so:

```
string = "27.116.56.0 27.116.59.255 43.230.209.0 43.230.209.255"  #(white space sep)
```

how would you go from it to this format:

```
string = "27.116.56.0-27.116.59.255,43.230.209.0-43.230.209.255"
```

**the string will have unknown length , the elements number will allways be even.

I've looked at some close examples and got confused..
what is the best easy way doing that?

Comment: Don't name your variables `string` as it will stomp on the `string` module

Comment: are all the strings exactly like this? There's 3 segments?

Comment: the string will have unknown length , the elements number will even.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general solution, you can [iterate over your split string in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python) of 2.

```
s = "27.116.56.0 27.116.59.255 43.230.209.0 43.230.209.255".split()
print(",".join(["-".join(s[i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]))
#'27.116.56.0-27.116.59.255,43.230.209.0-43.230.209.255'
```

Join the inner chunks with a `"-"` and finally join the whole thing with `","`

Answer (score 2):

```
# Create a new list containing the ips
str_elems = "27.116.56.0 27.116.59.255 43.230.209.0 43.230.209.255".split()
# Use a format string to build the new representation, where each list element is assigned a spot in the string
# We use the * operator to convert the single list into multiple arguments for the format
new_str = ("{}-{},"*(len(str_elems)/2)).format(*str_elems).rstrip(',')
```

Comment: @TheoretiCAL the string will have unknown length , the elements number will allways be even.

Comment: @Avarage_joe I've updated it to support unknown length.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "27.116.56.0 27.116.59.255 43.230.209.0 43.230.209.255"

ip_list = string.split(" ")                     # split the string to a list using space seperator

for i in range(len(ip_list)):                   # len(ip_list) returns the number of items in the list (4)
                                                # range(4) resolved to 0, 1, 2, 3 

    if (i % 2 == 0): ip_list[i] += "-"          # if i is even number - concatenate hyphen to the current IP string 
    else: ip_list[i] += ","                     # otherwize concatenate comma

print("".join(ip_list)[:-1])                    # "".join(ip_list) - join the list back to a string
                                                # [:-1] trims the last character of the result (the extra comma)
```