# python - debugging: loop for plotting isn't showing the next plot

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I need help in debugging. I just can't figure out why it's not working as expected.

The Code below should read data files (names are stored in `all_files`) in chunks of 6, arrange them in subplots (i,j indices 0,0 top left, 1,2 bottom right), show plot.

It works for the first six file names and the plot is being showed. When I close the window of the plot, the code continues and ends without showing the next plot... is `plt.show()` at a wrong place?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=cond_row, ncols=cond_col)

k=0 # step
i=0 # indice
j=0 # indice

for z in range(0, len(all_files), 6):
    for fe in all_files[z:z+6]:
        get_name_tag = re.findall(".A(\d{7}).", all_files[k])[0]
        for label, values in data_1_band.items():
            if label == str(get_name_tag):
                axes[i, j].set_title("Band " + str(Band_names[specific_band]) +" - "+ "file: "+ str(label))
                axes[i, j].set_ylabel("Along-Track Scans")
                axes[i, j].set_xlabel("Along-Scan Scans")
                im1 = axes[i, j].imshow(values, interpolation="none")
                cb = fig.colorbar(im1, ax=axes[i, j], label='W $\mathrm{m^{-2}}$ $\mathrm{\mu m^{-1}}$ $\mathrm{ster^{-1}}$')

                # Taking mean from data and finds location on colorbar
                mean_loc = (L_B_1_mean[label] - cb.vmin) / (cb.vmax - cb.vmin)

                # add a horizontal line to the colorbar axis
                cb.ax.hlines(mean_loc, 0, 1, label="Mean")


        #Columns condition
        j=j+1
        k=k+1

        if j==3:
            print "entered if condition: new line"
            i=i+1
            j=0
            if i==2:     # Plot is full, resetting for next plot
                j=0
                i=0

    # deleting axes in case there are no 6 files left
    if len(all_files) < 4:
       fig.delaxes(axes[1][0])
       fig.delaxes(axes[1][1])
       fig.delaxes(axes[1][2])

    if len(all_files) < 5:
       fig.delaxes(axes[1][1])
       fig.delaxes(axes[1][2])

    if len(all_files) < 6:
       fig.delaxes(axes[1][2])  

    plt.show()
```

**Files:**

`all_files` looks like this:

```
MYD021KM.A2009049.0930.006.2012060021525.hdf
MYD021KM.A2010305.0900.006.2012070143225.hdf
MYD021KM.A2010321.0900.006.2012071073516.hdf
MYD021KM.A2010337.0900.006.2012071175047.hdf
MYD021KM.A2010353.0900.006.2012072063847.hdf
MYD021KM.A2010001.0900.006.2012065165320.hdf
.....
```

`data_1_band`: (How can I upload a file, so you could run the code?)

```
2009161 [[ 3.58403872  3.57167339  3.60095971 ...,  7.01769751  6.80943921
   6.88883769]
 [ 3.40962239  3.51960881  3.54954594 ...,  6.97864908  6.89404414
   7.03657092]
 [ 3.26384158  3.51244993  3.63089684 ...,  6.89729818  6.99491926
   7.11922343]
 ..., 
 [ 8.26724734  8.05183015  7.79801534 ...,  8.21583357  8.24316747
   8.24772312]
 [ 8.17288029  8.11691087  7.66655229 ...,  8.21648437  8.20281742
   8.09998989]
 [ 8.26659653  7.93012921  7.49929484 ...,  8.19305531  8.18849966
   8.10845038]]
2009065 [[ 6.12674245  6.25950712  6.74045364 ...,  7.12377909  7.11076294
   7.0977468 ]
 [ 6.08509079  6.22761757  6.86215459 ...,  7.13093796  7.12247747
   7.11336617]
 [ 6.07728111  6.19702963  6.61745108 ...,  7.13939846  7.12573151
   7.11727101]
 ...,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that plt.show() is inside the loop. Generally, it should only be called once, after all the figures have been created. Because once it’s called, matplotlib thinks it’s done.

To solve this, I had to move `fig, axes = plt.subplots…` inside the first for-loop, and add a fig.close() after plt.show().