# How to devide loop into several stages

Tags: python, loops

i have a loop for 2001 files:

```py
for i in tqdm(result_file_list):
    df = read_pickle(file_path, i)
    final_df += df
```

and i want to save final_df every 100 files, whats the easiest way yo do it?

i have in mind only smth like this:

```py
for i in tqdm(result_file_list[:100]):
    df = read_pickle(file_path, i)
    final_df += df
```

```py
for i in tqdm(result_file_list[100:200]):
    df = read_pickle(file_path, i)
    final_df += df
```

Comment: Is `final_df` cumulative or a new variable every 100 files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This should help, calculate how many iterations (your stages)

```
import math

#2001 / 100 = 20.01 (21 iteration, round it up 20.01 > 21)

stages = math.ceil(2001/100.0)

#for z in xrange(stages): #python2
for z in range(stages): #python3
    for i in tqdm(result_file_list[i*x: (i*z)+100]):
        your_code()
```

Comment: I use python 3 and it gives me error for xrange and x