# Iterating over a list, yielded from a method, one element at a time

Tags: python, list, iteration, yield

I'm trying to make a method that iterates over a list and returns the next element.

That's listDenominations:

> [2, 5, 7, 10, 25, 30, 50, 70]

That's the method I'm working on:

```
class SomeClass

    def iterDenominations(self):
        it = iter(self.listDenominations)
        yield it.__next__()

# much later in the code
C = SomeClass()
```

When I call the method and print the result

```
firstCall = C.iterDenominations()
print(firstCall)
secondCall = C.iterDenominations()
print(secondCall)
```

, the first two prints are:

> <generator object Currency.iterDenominations at 0x000001D413F6DC10>

> <generator object Currency.iterDenominations at 0x000001D4140E2EB0>

These are not the results I was expecting. I'm looking for the elements to be returned sequentially from listDenominations i.e.

after firstCall: [2]

after secondCall: [5]

after thirdCall (as yet unwritten): [7], etc.

[Pehaps related to this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python)

Comment: Don't use `__next__()` instead call `next()` builtin function

Comment: Do you want `firstCall` to be 2 and `secondCall` to be 5?

Answer (score 2):

```py
iterable = iter(self.listDenominations)
for item in iterable:
    yield item
```

or

```py
yield from iterable
```

Calling a generator function will create a generator, it will not return a value from the generator. So, you create the generator, then call `next` on it (or iterate over it)

```py
denominations = c.iterDenominations()  # make the generator
first_call = next(denominations)
second_call = next(denomination)
rest = list(denominations)
print(first_call, second_call, rest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple class for returning 3 next elements:

```
class IterDenominations(object):
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.iterator = iter(numbers)

    def next(self):
        print([next(self.iterator), next(self.iterator), next(self.iterator)])
```

Test:

```
ids = IterDenominations([2, 5, 7, 10, 25, 30, 50, 70])
ids.next()
ids.next()
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 7]
[10, 25, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write a function with `yield`, calling it doesn't return that value. It returns a special type of object called a `generator`.To print out all the values of a `generator`,you will have to either loop over it with of `for` or pull it into a `list` or `tuple`.
Printing code:

```py
firstCall = C.iterDenominations()
print(list(firstCall))
secondCall = C.iterDenominations()
print(list(secondCall))
```

Also,calling `__next__` in your function is not a good practice, nor does it give you all the elements. The more pythonic way of doing so is this:

```py
    def iterDenominations(self):
        it = iter(self.listDenominations)
        yield from it
```

or simply

```py
def iterDenominations(self):
    return self.listDenominations
```