# How to space letters according to a specific number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to achieve the next thing. When I put the `s` as a string such as `"Hello"`, I want it to split for the number in `part_length`. Meaning that if I put `1` in `part_length`, the operation result would be: `"H e l l o s"`, if I put `2` in `part_length`, it would print `"He ll os"`

This is the code I have now:

```
def split_in_parts(s, part_length):
    for num in range(part_length):

print(split_in_parts("Hellos", 1))
```

But I can't figure out how to split the words according to the numbers, which I believe I lack the knowledge in commands. I've tried commands such as `' '.join()` but in that case it separates in a way that it is not accordingly to the numbers.

Comment: Split into chunks and then join for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you told you don't know many functions, I tried to keep it as simple as possible.
I finally got this

```
def split_in_parts(s, part_length):
    new_str= ''
    L = []
    for i in s:
        L.append(i)
    while len(L)!=0:
        for i in range(part_length):
            ele = L.pop(L.index(L[0]))
            new_str+=ele
        new_str+=' '
    return new_str
```

Comment: How is this simple? Two loops and one embedded loop. This is needlessly complex, computationally not efficient at all.

Comment: This is NOT the optimal solution and should not have been selected as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method using `zip_longest` and `' '.join()` -

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def split_in_parts(string, part_length):
    chunk = zip_longest(*[iter(string)]*part_length, fillvalue='')
    return ' '.join([''.join(i) for i in chunk])

print(split_in_parts('hellos', 1))
print(split_in_parts('hellos', 2))
print(split_in_parts('hellos', 3))
```

```
h e l l o s
he ll os
hel los
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy with a list comprehension that uses a for loop with a step size of `part_length`. So first you collect the character groups that you expect, and then you join them together.

```py
def split_in_parts(s: str, part_length: int) -> str:
    char_groups = [s[idx:idx+part_length] for idx in range(0, len(s), part_length)]
    return " ".join(char_groups)
        

print(split_in_parts("Hellos", 2))
# He ll os
```