# How do I read n bytes at a time from a large string in python

Tags: python-3.x

This seems like it shouldn't be hard but I cannot find an example of doing this with a string, only with a file.  I have a large string (3.5 mb).  I want to loop over the string while reading n bytes per loop and perform an action on each chunk.  What is the easiest way to do this?  I'd prefer to do this with standard python libraries, not third party.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to iterate over bytes or unicode codepoints? If the latter, then does this answer your question? [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python)

Comment: The code I have is in an aws lambda.  It's a string being passed into the lambda.  I need to process the string in 5000 byte chunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
very_long_string = "very_long_string"
n = 3
for i in range(0, len(very_long_string), n):
    substring = very_long_string[i:i+n]
    # DO PROCESSING HERE
```

Comment: n represents number of chars?  I would like to chunk the string on n = 5000 bytes or n = 5 kb.

Comment: Yes, n is the number of chars. Assuming you are using ascii encoding, 1 char is one byte.