# How to add time delay for every 10 lists of completion in python threadpool execution?

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multithreading, sleep, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a list with a length of 100. and I am running it concurrently with threadpool. I can add the time delay inside the executing function, but I would like to have a code that automatically sleeps for X seconds when 10  successful thread execution happen.

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

user_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,...,100]

def parse(user):
    return str(user) + "parsed!"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as exe:
   start = time.time()
   result = exe.map(parse,user_list)
   output = list(result)
   end = time.time()
   print('taken time' end-start)
```

I want to add a time delay between each 10 successful thread executions. I hope my question is clear, and it can be solved with some sheduling

Comment: Iterate over the list in chunks of 10, pass each chunk to exe.map and sleep at the end of each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way is to just submit up to 10 jobs at a time, then sleep between each chunk:

```
import itertools
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991553/51685
def chunker(n, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk


def parse(user):
    return f"{user} parsed!"


def main():
    user_list = list(range(100))
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as exe:
        for chunk in chunker(10, user_list):
            start = time.time()
            result = exe.map(parse, chunk)
            output = list(result)
            end = time.time()
            print(output, "taken time", end - start)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This prints out e.g.

```
['0 parsed!', '1 parsed!', '2 parsed!', '3 parsed!', '4 parsed!', '5 parsed!', '6 parsed!', '7 parsed!', '8 parsed!', '9 parsed!'] taken time 0.0006809234619140625
['10 parsed!', '11 parsed!', '12 parsed!', '13 parsed!', '14 parsed!', '15 parsed!', '16 parsed!', '17 parsed!', '18 parsed!', '19 parsed!'] taken time 0.0008037090301513672
['20 parsed!', '21 parsed!', '22 parsed!', '23 parsed!', '24 parsed!', '25 parsed!', '26 parsed!', '27 parsed!', '28 parsed!', '29 parsed!'] taken time 0.0008540153503417969
...
```

## EDIT for tqdm progress

To use `tqdm` with this approach so it gets updated on each `parse` step, you'll need something like the below (bits identical to the above replaced with `...`).

(`tqdm` won't update the screen unless enough time has passed since the last time it did, hence the random sleep to represent work done.)

```
def parse(user, prog):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(.1, 1.3))  # Do work here...
    prog.update()  # Step the progress bar.
    return f"{user} parsed!"


def main():
    # ...
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as exe, tqdm.tqdm(total=len(user_list)) as prog:
        for chunk in chunker(10, user_list):
            # ...
            result = exe.map(parse, chunk, [prog] * len(chunk))
            # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have one small query, How can I track how many have succeeded. I have used `tqdm` library it does work with each chunk but it's not interactive, any help on that. @AKX

Comment: Sure – added an example on how to use tqdm with this.

Answer (score 0):

I made a global variable which counts the number of times the `parse()` function has run and whenever it is completely divisible by 10(`no_of_times_run % 10 == 0`) it sleeps for a certain amount of time.

Code attached for your reference.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

user_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,...,100]

no_of_times_run = 0

def parse(user):
    global no_of_times_run

    no_of_times_run += 1
    if no_of_times_run % 10 == 0:
        time.sleep(1) # Every 10th time it sleeps for a certain time.

    return str(user) + "parsed!"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as exe:
   start = time.time()
   result = exe.map(parse,user_list)
   output = list(result)
   end = time.time()
   print('taken time', end-start)
```

Comment: I like the concept, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try creating a list with 100 values with `list(range(1, 101)` instead of using Ellipsis(`...`) and testing it.