# For returning 3 result each loop

Tags: python

can someone help me out.

I need a loop that returns 3 results from a list for each loop

Example:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

for x in lst:
    print(x[0])
    print(x[1])
    print(x[2])
```

> should return
>
> 1,2,3
>
> 4,5,6
>
> 7,8,9
>
> 10,11,12
>
> 13,14,15
>
> 16

im using flask

```
{% for i in getdataasset %}
    {{getdataasset[i]}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991506/iterate-an-iterator-by-chunks-of-n-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Use slices

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

for i in range(0,len(lst),3):
    print(*lst[i:i+3])
```

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16
```

Comment: should have mention im using flask. dont recognize len