# Is there an iter which accepts a complex sentinel?

Tags: python, iterator, sentinel

I use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) with two arguments and was wondering if there is an equivalent which would accept a more complex sentinel?

As an example, in the code below

```
# returns digits 1 to 10 upon subsequently calling .create(), 
# then returns 'END' each time afterwards
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def create(self):
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter > 10:
            return 'END'
        else:
            return self.counter

c = MyClass()
for i in iter(c.create, 'END'):
    print(i)
```

the iteration ends upon getting `'END'`. I would like to have it end after getting, say, a total of two `'END'` (not necessarily one after the other - the code above will generate only `'END'` after the first ten calls but one can imagine a case where they are interlaced with other values).

**In essence, I am looking for a way to use a more complex sentinel.** Is there such a concept?

I know I can resort to the obvious-but-ugly code mentioned in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393276/how-to-get-chunks-of-elements-from-a-queue), hovewer @HappyLeapSecond answer is so elegant I would like to keep the spirit (I went though [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) but none of the available methods seem to do the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) with a stateful `predicate`. For example:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> def create_predicate(func, max_count):
    """Return False only when func evaluates True for the max_count time."""
    def predicate(elem):
        if func(elem):
            predicate.count += 1
        if predicate.count == max_count:
            return False
        return True
    predicate.count = 0
    return predicate

>>> list(takewhile(create_predicate(lambda elem: elem % 3 == 0, 3), range(1, 20)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

In the example above, `create_predicate(lambda elem: elem % 3 == 0, 3)` creates a complex predicate function that will stop the iteration on the third multiple of three. In your case,

> I would like to have it end after getting, say, a total of two `'END'`

you could use `create_predicate(lambda elem: elem == 'END', 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using a generator:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def create(self, func, number):
        while number:
            self.counter += 1
            if func(self.counter):
                yield 'END'
                number -= 1
            else:
                yield self.counter
```

Here's how it works:

```
>>> def foo(n):
    return n % 3 == 0
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> for i in c.create(foo, 3):
    print(i)

1
2
END
4
5
END
7
8
END
```

I think this keeps things fairly simple (possibly too simple for your use case but your example is quite simple).